# iOS Push Notification SDK for Cordova

Tags: iphone, cordova

I want to implement push notification for **Cordova**.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/)

And also downloaded the sample project

But I am unable to find `Cordova.plist/Cordova.plist` and don't have knowledge to configure this.

If somebody has already worked on this, please help on this point

Any type of suggestions and advice are welcome at this stage

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a typo.

It should be in the folder of the same name as your app in your project folder.

If your app was called `MyCoolApp` and it was in the `MyCoolAppProject` folder, say... the plist file would be:

`MyCoolAppProject/MyCoolApp/Cordova.plist`

However, as of `2.3.0RC1`, `Cordova.plist` has been superseded by `config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

there are no more .plist file in cordova, add your plugin to config.xml